# Maximum call stack size exceeded when returning promise after Firebase transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a Firebase cloud function, which will perform a transaction operation on Firebase real-time database and return promises and some data when I call it directly from my web app.

Currently, my function looks like this:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    //reference of a node from Firebase real-time database
    var db = admin.database().ref('node');

    return db.transaction(function(snap){
        if(snap){
          if(snap == 'value'){
            snap = 'new value';
          }
        }
        return snap;
    },
    function(error, committed, datasnapshot){
        if (error) {
          var userId = 'a user id';
          return admin.auth().deleteUser(userId).then(function() {
            return {msg: error.message};
          });
        }
        else if (!committed) {
          var userId = 'a user id';
          return admin.auth().deleteUser(userId).then(function() {
            return {msg: 'transaction aborted'};
          });
        }
        else{
          //transaction complete
          var database = admin.database().ref('another node');
          return db.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
            if(snapshot.val() == 'new value'){
                return database.set('some_data').then(function(datasnap){
                    return {msg: 'done'};
                });
            }
            else{
                return {msg: 'not done'};
            }
          }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is this function is giving an error: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". It seems that somehow an endless recursive function call is occurring which is causing this error.

I tried removing **return** from **return db.transaction()**, but after that, the function doesn't return anything to the client from where I am calling this function.

Why is this function behaving like this? And what should I change in my code to return the data to the client without any error?